# Highcharts - Dropdown Line Chart with Multiple Lines

Tags: javascript, highcharts, visualization

I'm working on a data visualization in Highcharts. My data is made up of a list of communities with associated data. It looks something like:

```
const data = [
{name: "Community", data: [#, #, #, ...]},
{name: "Community2", data: [#, #, #, ...]},
...etc
]
```

I have a dropdown with the options Community, Community2, etc. that allows a user to choose which line to see. However, I'm trying to also add an option to show all lines at once. The individual lines work, but I can't seem to find a way to get the all option to work. Instead, it defaults to the first community in the list. If I make the series by default `data`, then the individual lines don't work.

I assume there's something in Highcharts I'm missing, as I'm quite new to the library. I've put together a short example of this in JSFiddle. The way it works right now is it adds an action listener to the dropdown and updates the chart whenever to however it changes. Another note: I've used JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(...)) quite a bit here to avoid aliasing issues, I don't think this is the best solution, but it's what works right now and I'm not too sure what else to do to avoid the issue of modifying the data itself (since I believe that's what Highcharts does on update, which was an issue before).

TL;DR:
The expected behavior: The dropdown allows users to choose which line to see. The "All" choice would show all lines.

Current behavior: The individual lines work, but the all choice defaults to the first line instead of showing multiple lines.

Thank you!

http://jsfiddle.net/v36c01wg/24/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to set to `true` the parameter `oneToOne` of the call to `chart.update`. From the [docs](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#update):

> When the oneToOne parameter is true, chart.update will also take care of adding and removing items from the collection.

```js
var data = [{
    data: [6, 7, 5, 2, 1, 8, 3, 4, 7, 1, 5, 2],
    name: "Display Text 1",
    id: "dt1"
  },
  {
    data: [9, 8, 8, 1, 5, 2, 4, 8, 9, 7, 8, 6],
    name: "Display Text 2",
    id: "dt2"
  }
];

const ogData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data.filter((obj) => {
  return obj.name === "Display Text 1";
})));


var chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
  xAxis: {
    categories: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
  },

  series: ogData
});

const dropdown = document.getElementById("select");

dropdown.addEventListener("change", (event) => {
  if (event.target.value === "All Lines") {
    chart.update({
      series: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data))
    }, true, true)
    // no need for this, as per @ppotaczek's comment
    // chart.redraw();
  } else {
    chart.update({
      series: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data.filter((obj) => {
        return obj.name === event.target.value;
      })))
    }, true, true)

    // no need for this, as per @ppotaczek's comment
    // chart.redraw();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<select id="select">
  <option value="Display Text 1">Display Text 1</option>
  <option value="Display Text 2">Display Text 2</option>
  <option value="All Lines">All Lines</option>
</select>

<div id="container" style="height: 300px"></div>
```

You'll have to set the colors also, otherwise highcharts will evolve colors with each update, since it will consider each newly activated dataset a completely new one.

I have to say that I think your `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(...))` is a little bit excessive, but I'm sure you'll replace it in production code with some cloning method that is more efficient and specific to your data.

Comment: I want to add that `chart.redraw()` doesn't need to be called after `chart.update()`. And also, you can check `allowMutatingData` option: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.allowMutatingData